# DataTables & Ruby - limit one statement within an each block?

Tags: ruby, datatables, slim

I want to prevent "td= ticket_order.notes" from listing the notes on each row, and limit the notes to the first row of that order. Currently, when a purchaser has multiple tickets (each ticket is a row), the notes are listed on each ticket.  I need the notes listed only once on the first row and I'm not sure how to go about it. Is this something I can do with DataTables?

```
   tbody
  - decorated_report.ticket_orders.each do |ticket_order|
    tr
      - if decorated_report.reserved_seating?
        td= ticket_order.table_and_seat
      td= ticket_order.section_name
      td data-sort="#{ticket_order.purchaser_last_name}, #{ticket_order.purchaser_first_name}" #{ticket_order.purchaser_name}
      td= ticket_order.purchaser_telephone_number
      td= ticket_order.date_purchased
      td= number_to_currency(ticket_order.amount_paid)
      td= ticket_order.purchase_method
      td= ticket_order.notes
```

Comment: Your two screenshots are perfectly identical. Furthermore, [images of plaintext are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste the data into the question. You have many [markdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) to make it look like a table.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `each_with_index`, then you can keep track of the index and only *conditionally* show the notes (if the index is zero):

```
- decorated_report.ticket_orders.each_with_index do |ticket_order, idx|
  tr
    / ... other stuff
    - if idx == 0
      td= ticket_order.notes
```

Comment: What if the index variable?

Comment: @BradSaid then you pass the variable to slim the same way that are you doing with the other variables you use (such as `decorated_report`)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an array, pushing the purchaser IDs into it, and then checking to see if the ID was present more than once in the array.  If so, do nothing, if not, add the notes

```
    - decorated_report.ticket_orders.each do |ticket_order|
    - ids.push(ticket_order.purchaser_id)
    tr
      - if decorated_report.reserved_seating?
        td= ticket_order.table_and_seat
      td= ticket_order.section_name
      td data-sort="#{ticket_order.purchaser_last_name}, #{ticket_order.purchaser_first_name}" #{ticket_order.purchaser_name}
      td= ticket_order.purchaser_telephone_number
      td= ticket_order.date_purchased
      td= number_to_currency(ticket_order.amount_paid)
      td= ticket_order.purchase_method
      - if ids.count(ticket_order.purchaser_id) > 1
        td=
      - else
        td= ticket_order.notes
```